# How to use code from a project in a maven repository

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to use code from this project: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib, and I am trying to do this with intelij. In the instructions provided with the library it simply says to add this to build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.3.0'
}
```

however when I add this and try to use code from the project intelij gives errors such as unable to resolve symbol, etc. So I am wondering what are the other steps needed to use code from this project that must be done using intelij. Any help is appreciated.

My build.gradle file currently looks like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6+'

}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAds.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2')
compile files('libs/amazon-ads-5.1.10.jar')
compile project('libraries/cardslib/library')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
}


dependencies {
// Cards Library
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:0.6.0'
compile project(':libraries:cardslib:library')
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use it from Maven Cental? `compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.3.0'`

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant to have written originally. I tried doing that but I dont understand how you can use the code from the project just by doing that. What other steps need to be taken ?

Comment: I retagged this from Maven to Gradle, but maybe that was incorrect. Which of these are you using for dependency management?

Comment: I had been using gradle before but I guess now I need to be using maven in order to use this project as a dependency. I am not 100% sure

Comment: I guess there are two version of the library - sources is latest and maven is an older 0.6.0 - and they are conflict with each other.

Comment: are you behind a proxy by any chance ?

Comment: You are using 2 versions of the same lib.
compile project(':libraries:cardslib:library') is not required if you are using the maven version.
Also, update your script. The current lib version is 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

The documents here are also helpful to new Maven users.

1. Download and Install Maven - Download the latest version of Maven and install it
2. Quick Start - Get started building the project quickly
3. Use Maven - Learn how to use Maven on your own project

Refer this the below link to get much more details...

http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the maven central repository to your build file.
The simplest way is to just put this in your `build.gradle` directly under `apply plugin: 'android'`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Resync your IDE with the gradle file after doing so.
It should resolve the dependency like any other maven central dependency (e.g. ABS).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sources (git repo cloned) at rootProject/libraries/cardslib, then add its library in rootProject/settings.gradle:

```
include ':appModule', ':libraries:cardslib:library'
```

and then in rootProject/appModule/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:cardslib:library')
}
```

**Or**, if you use maven, then just do this in rootProject/appModule/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.3.0'
}
```

so the library's jar/aar will be downloaded in ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/... and be compiled.

Pick one of above, don't do both.

Comment: I am a bit confused. In my project I have the root folder and in that I have a build.gradle and settings.gradle. Also, in my MainModule folder there is just a build.gradle file. Which is the one I should be changing, and do I need both of them?

Comment: When using sources, edit root's settings.gradle and MainModule's build.gradle. When using maven archive, edit MainModule's build.gradle only.

Comment: What is the equivalent of an Eclipse .psf file? Where do I store the information, which git repos need to be cloned where for the project to work? Can gradle clone those repos automatically for me when initializing the project?